# Pull Content from JSON file (Same Server)

Tags: json

I am not clear about something and need your kind help. I have a JSON file in the same theme and I want to open the json file to get the content. I know wp_remote_get is for remote request. What function will I use for same domain requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you're requesting from server side or front end.

In PHP you can use file_get_contents() function.

In jQuery, you can use the HTTP get.